# Can a JRE be configured to require SecurityManager settings?

Tags: java, security, securitymanager

I'd like to set up a unix user with a highly restricted set of permissions for any java code they might try to execute. (This is a layer of security in addition to unix file permissions and iptables.)

I can set up the system-wide java policy file at `java.home/lib/security/java.policy` with those restrictions.

How can I require all invocations of the JRE to run with a SecurityManager enabled (i.e. with `-Djava.security.manager`) **and** to prevent the user from adding grants via a `-Djava.security.policy=someURL` argument?